# How to find Android app responsible for ARP spoofing?

Tags: applications, adb, wi-fi, diagnostics

A family member's OnePlus 7T (latest factory firmware) keeps trying to sporadically but frequently ARP spoof the local default gw address on our wifi.

Is there a way, perhaps involving `adb`, that would help me find the app or process responsible?

(I'm fairly certain it's the phone, and not some device that tries to implicate the phone, because it only happens when the phone is actually around.)

Comment: Arp spoofing requires root access, so the malware can escape from the app sandbox and install itself somewhere else. Thus deleting the app may not solve the infection. Perform a factory reset and hope that this fixes all problems.

Comment: Let's assume for a moment that it is not malware that would want to hide itself, but some app like WifiKill or NetCut; or a misfeature of the ROM (I'm not even sure it's rooted, will have to check). How would you go about finding whatever it is, in case it's not deliberately hidden?